# Python script wont shut down PC

Tags: python

Im trying to implement a script where python will shutdown my pc given a certain varaible. At first i tested the to see if i could shutdown python using the following script:

```py
import os 
  
shutdown = input("Do you wish to shutdown your computer ? (yes / no): ") 
  
if shutdown == 'no':       
    exit() 
else: 
    os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
```

instead of shutting down the pc, it just opens a cmd prompt which asks: Do you wish to shutdown your computer ? (yes / no): and if i type yes it just asks the question on repeat without shutting it down, and if i put no it just closes the window.

Comment: What is your os?

Comment: Does that shutdown command work when you type it normally at a command prompt?

Comment: It's pendantic, but your Python program will exit as soon as it passes the codnitional anyway,  so your code is equivalent to just `if shutdown != 'no': os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")`

Comment: "if i type yes it just asks the question on repeat", there is no loop in your code shown here, you need to create a real [mcve]

Comment: If you have a file called "shutdown" somewhere near your script then try to rename it.

Comment: Is this a plain python script, or did you compile it into an executable named `shutdown.exe` ?

Comment: Rename all shutdown.* files you have created recently to shutdown2.*. Otherwise your program may run itself from os.system.

Comment: See [ask]. Do a preliminary debugging. Anyway, do like ```os.system("%windir%/system32/shutdown.exe /s /t 1")```.